# $\Bbb R^n-\{k$ points$\}$ are all homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

If $p$ and $q$ are any two points in $\Bbb R^n$, then $\Bbb R^n-\{p\}$ and $\Bbb R^n-\{q\}$ are homeomorphic, by a translation. Is this true for $k$ points? I.e., if $p_1,\dots,p_k,q_1,\dots,q_k \in \Bbb R^n$ then do we necessarily have $\Bbb R^n -\{p_1,\dots,p_k\}\cong \Bbb R^n-\{q_1,\dots,q_k\}$?

Comment: If all the $p_i$'s are distinct and all the $q_j$'s are also all distinct, then yes. But it's kind of annoying to write something precisely, a drawing is better !

Comment: The keyword you should look up is "isotopy extension".

Comment: I think Brouwer first showed this as part of his paper in which he shows all $\Bbb R^n$ are countable dense homogeneous (as it's now called), early 1900's.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Wonderful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is true, and as AlexL says it's kind of annoying to write down such a homeomorphism explicitly, although for $k = 2$ a translation, a rotation, and a scale suffices, and for $n = 1$ we just get a union of open intervals (two of which are infinite) and we can scale each interval separately.

I think this works: they are in fact diffeomorphic, and we can write down a diffeomorphism from one to the other by writing down a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose flow $\phi_t$ at some time $t$ satisfies $\phi_t(p_i) = q_{\pi(i)}$ for some permutation of the indices $\pi$ (although we don't really need the permutation when $n \ge 2$). We can do this by writing some smooth curves connecting each pair of points, parameterized so that they're all traversed in the same time $t$, then writing down a smooth vector field which restricts to the velocity vector of each curve. There's a huge amount of slack available in how to do this (one of the reasons it's kind of annoying to write down); we can do it using [bump functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function), for example.